# Scrollmagic triggerElement not working

Tags: javascript, scrollmagic

I have a Scrollmagic problem: I am using triggerElement, but it says that it enters the triggerElement at the top of the page, yet the triggerElement is at the middle of the page.  This is my ScrollMagic code:

```
var scene2 = new ScrollMagic.Scene({triggerElement: "#motivational"})
.setPin("#MiddleOfPage") // pins the element for the the scene's duration
.addTo(controller);
```

The #middleOfPage is a fixed element at the middle of the page, and the "motivational" element is the id of a relative element in the middle of the page.  I don't know what happened!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the triggerHook

```
var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        triggerElement:'#motivational',
        triggerHook: 0

        }).setPin('#MiddleOfPage')
          .addIndicators() // add indicators (requires plugin)
          .addTo(controller);
```

The triggerHook can take a Int as a value. You can set the breakpoint anywhere on the page.